# bool object is not callable when running subprocess.run - pycharm bug?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, pycharm, subprocess

I'm getting a strange warning in Pycharm, I wanted to check it is a mistake with Pycharm and not my code.

I use subprocess.run to call certain external commands:

```py
with open(log.txt, 'w+') as log:
    subprocess.run('echo "hello world"', shell=True, stdout=log, stderr=log)
```

Now, this works fine and shows no errors. However, if I add a condition:

```py
if condition:
    with open(log.txt, 'w+') as log:
        subprocess.run('echo "hello world"', shell=True, stdout=log, stderr=log)
```

Pycharm now throws a warning "bool object not callable". Is this just a Pycharm error (as obviously I'm calling a string command) or is there something deeper going on here?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You either did `open = <True/False`, or `subprocess.run = <True/False>` before these lines are getting exected. Please paste the full code, we cannot really give productive answer from this little snippet

Comment: Does PyCharm at least indicate which line the attempted call occurs on?

Comment: @chepner The error highlights the subprocess.run() line itself.

Comment: If it's really just a *warning*, then yes, it sounds like a PyCharm bug. Otherwise, you would appear to have overwritten the `run` attribute of the `subprocess` module with a Boolean value.